# ClassNotFoundException when using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When I run my code, I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver; with a stack trace link to line 13 (Highlighted in the code)

I have just started using JDBC and don't know much about it, but I'll go through what I have done so far to get to where I am. As a preliminary, I am using MySQL Workbench and Apache Netbeans 11:

1) Downloaded the .jar connector file

2) Could not find the build path on netbeans 11 and did some research and couldn't find any resources linking to it, so instead used the Driver dropdown through the databases section on the services tab. Now I can see all my SQL databases and tables in my netbeans IDE.

3) Wrote the following code using the 7 steps to connect to the database, establish a connection etc

```
import java.sql.*;

public class GroundControlToMajorTom {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306//customers";
        String uname = "root";
        String pass = "";
        String query = "SELECT customer_id FROM customers WHERE customer_id = 1";

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pass);

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);


        rs.next();
        String id = rs.getString("customer_id");

        System.out.println(id);

        st.close();
        con.close();

    }
}
```

4) Run the code and get a ClassNotFoundException. I did a bit of research and it seems to say that I don't have the connection to the actual driver, but I added it in the drivers section of the services for my project?

Any help would be much appreciated my dudes <3

Comment: add `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `CLASSPATH`

Comment: When `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` execute , `classloader` try to load `Dricever`. When driver are loading, execute side effects (like initialization `static fields` add `blocks`), which required to execute `JDBC` library

Comment: Adding drivers to the "drivers section of the services for my project" makes the driver available to NetBeans for connecting to the database from within NetBeans itself. To be able to use it from your application, it needs to be on the classpath (build path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `CLASSPATH`.

If you use `maven`, add to `<dependencies>` section of `pom.xml` the dependency of required driver (`mysql-connector-java`):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>${mysql.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

for `gradle`

```
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: mysqlVersion
```

Comment: can I just add that anywhere in the pom.xml file?

Comment: There is an error when trying to add that code, I am adding this change:  <version>${8.0.20}</version> and the error being called is saying that the dependency is an unrecognised tag?

Comment: add to `<dependencies> `section

Comment: `<version>${mysql.version}</version>`  is a variable **=>** `<version>8.0.20</version>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the downloaded JAR to the classpath.

Try this instruction:

1. Open NetBeans and right-click on the project name in the Projects tab.
2. Select Properties.
3. Select Libraries.
4. Click the Add Jar/Folder button.
5. Navigate to the directory where the downloaded JAR files are.

Comment: Hi, For some reason in my properties there isn't a libraries section?

Comment: @BurnerBoiii - What is `build and dependencies management system` you use?

Comment: I am using java with maven at the moment, should I be using java with Ant?

Comment: @BurnerBoiii - Does `<artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>` exist in `pom.xml`?

Comment: No, I cannot see it there

Comment: In the case of maven, add mysql-connector-java to <dependencies> section in pom.xml.  Mysql dep is here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.20